# ASP.NET Core WebAPI: Validation of the provided antiforgery token failed. The cookie token and the request token were swapped

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, x-xsrf-token

In my ASP.NET Core 2 WebAPI application I want to use the AntiforgeryToken for my POST, PUT and DELETE controller methods. Reagrding to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery) I set up the `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods of my `Startup` class. On the client side I use Angular 5 and their default configuration for Antiforgery. I can't figure out where the problem is.

Here is a excerpt of my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "XSRF-TOKEN";
        options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
        options.FormFieldName = "F-XSFR-TOKEN";
    });
    // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider provider, ILogger<Startup> logger, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
    // ...
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
        await next();
    });
    // ...
}
```

My Controllers are all like that one:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api")]
public class CarController : Controller
{
    #region Variables
    private readonly DataContext _db;
    private ILogger<CarController> _logger;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public CarController(DataContext db, ILogger<CarController> logger)
    {
        _db = db;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("[controller]")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(_db.Cars);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.GetHashCode(), ex, ex.Message);
            return BadRequest(ex);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost("[controller]")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] CreateCar model)
    {
        try
        {
            // Creates a new car.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.HResult, ex, ex.Message);
            return StatusCode(500, ex);
        }
    }

    [HttpPut("[controller]/{id}")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int id, [FromBody] UpdateCar model)
    {
        try
        {
            // Updates a car
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.HResult, ex, ex.Message);
            return StatusCode(500, ex);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same problem and I think I found the issue.

**TLDR:** `options.Cookie.Name = "ASP-XSRF-TOKEN";`

The `options.Cookie.Name` in the `AddAntiforgery` **has to be different** than the cookie you set manually using `context.Response.Cookies.Append`.

Try to change the name of one of them and it will work. Right now you override the generated cookie that is using the `options.Cookie.Name` name with the `tokens.RequestToken` value.

You can notice the difference in the Developer Tools.

- The default token generated using `options.Cookie.Name` is marked as `http only` (`HttpOnly = true`)
- The manually attached token using `context.Response.Cookies.Append` is marked as `HttpOnly = false`

The second one is read from JS/Angular (you can read it in JS because the `HttpOnly=false` and sent as a header in your ajax requests and validated against the default one that can't be read from JS)